# using remote storage with Mozilla Lightning Calendar

Tags: linux, thunderbird, calendar, lightning

I intent to use Mozilla Thunderbird with Lightning Calendar add-on at my office.

My problem is that I do not want to store calendar entries on a local database file. I would like to have this file on a remote storage accessed by Lightning (i.e. another PC on my intranet).

I have already a linux (ubuntu) server plugged to my router for all office PCs to access (used as a file and internal web server for various necessary services).

I do not want to import/export entries. Backup is not problem. My problem is that I would like to "empty" calendar entries by "shutting down" the remote service in case of certain kind of situations.

Is this feasible? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lightning supports [CalDAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CalDAV) as an online calendar synchronization protocol. There are several Linux CalDAV servers (e.g. Radicale, NextCloud 13, Cyrus, others), and it's commonly supported by online calendar services (e.g. by Google Calendar).

Note that the calendar information will still be cached on the local disk, even though the server is primary storage (basically the same way that IMAP mail works).